# Creating a base type so I can parameterize a method to expect an id property

Tags: scala, case-class

I have a class that represents a user:

```
case class User(id: Int, name: String, age: Int)
```

I have a method that looks like this currently:

```
def whenOrdering[A](result: => A)(someValue: Int) = {
   if (someValue == 0) doSomething(".....")
   else fooBar(result)
}
```

What I want to do, is for every `result` that is passed in, I want to do:

```
else fooBar(result.copy(id = someValue)
```

So for this to happen, I want to create a base class for my models like:

```
abstract class BaseEntity {
  def id:Int // is this correct?????
}
```

So I want to change the method `whenOrdering` so that for every result type that is passed in, it expects a class that inherits from the BaseEntity.
So that I can perform the result.copy(id = someValue) operation.

is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

copy is defined on case classes.

case classes can't be extended.

To eliminate this you can

```
abstract class BaseEntity {
  def id:Int
  def copyWithId(id: Int): BaseEntity
}

case class User(id: Int, name: String, age: Int) extend BaseEntity{
  override def copyWithId(id: Int) = this.copy(id = id)
}
```

Comment: You can also make `copyWithId` return the original class and not `BaseEntity` if it is parameterized with a self-type. i.e. `abstract class BaseEntity[A] { self: A =>`

Comment: You certainly can name the `copyWithId` method `copy`; it just means case classes which extend `BaseEntity` won't get a new compiler-defined `copy` method.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov yes, but the whole point is me using that .copy method that the case class has :)